# room. чтение определенной колонки

Tags: android, android-room

В одной из активити мне нужно прочитать лишь один единственный элемент колонки одной из таблиц. По совету урока `[https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/532-urok-8-room-query.html][1]` я создал вложенный класс без аннотации @entity

```
    @Entity(tableName = "description_table")
public class ModelDescription {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    private String description;


    public ModelDescription(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public class Description {
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
        public String description;


    }
}
```

в макете только одно textView

В активити такой код:

```
databaseHelper = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
BiographyDao descriptionDao = databaseHelper.getDescriptionDao();
description = String.valueOf(descriptionDao.getDescription().get(1));
tv_description.setText(description);



   @Dao
public interface DescriptionDao {
  @Query("SELECT description FROM description_table")
    List <ModelDescription.Description> getDescription();
}
```

вылезает ошибка java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Что я делаю не так? Как мне прочитать нужное поле?

Comment: Мало логов. Наверняка в них указана конкретная причина. У вложенные классы и не нужны, по идее. Попробуйте просто сразу строки получать так: `@Query("SELECT description FROM description_table") List <String> getDescription()`

Comment: вам нужно сделать отдельный dao-метод (запрос) на получение конкретной записи по ее ID. при выборе из списка получать ID и по нему получать дополнительную информацию, так работают с БД. / В третьей строке в имени descriptionDao не хватает буквы "o", это опечатка здесь или ошибка в коде?